# Swift 3: How to have a "global" button and action used in multiple controllers

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3

Say I have 20 view controllers that all require the same button and action, is there a way to avoid implementing the same ibaction in every controller? Should I be subclassing UIViewController with my action then basing my controllers on that subclass? Or are there other approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up following the protocol/value based approach outlined here -> [subclassing-can-suck-and-heres-why](http://krakendev.io/blog/subclassing-can-suck-and-heres-why)

In my case I have a "settings" button that's on several views.

```
protocol SettingsButtonRenderer {
    func goToSettings()
}

extension SettingsButtonRenderer where Self: UIViewController {
    func goToSettings() {
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let settingsNavigationController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingsNavigationController")
        present(settingsNavigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
     }
}

class DeliveryTabViewController: UIViewController, SettingsButtonRenderer {

    @IBOutlet weak var goToSettingBtn: UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        goToSettingBtn.target = self
        goToSettingBtn.action = #selector(DeliveryTabViewController.settingsClicked as (DeliveryTabViewController) -> () -> ())
    }

    func settingsClicked() {
        goToSettings()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass UIButton and create a convenience initializer.

```
public class CloseButton: UIButton {
    convenience init(
        tag     :Int,
        target  :Any,
        action  :Selector
        )
    {
        self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.setTitle("Close", for: .normal)
        self.tintColor = UIColor.white
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.tag = tag
        self.addTarget(target, action: action, for: .touchUpInside)
    }
}
```

- I write this kind of thing in code along with my AutoLayout, thus the reason for a frame of CGRect.zero.
- You can make the target/selector Optional. I used to have it that way but this is code only I consume.
- A convenience init() can also be made failable. Configure at your own discretion!
- Some of things may not be able to be set up in IB, but most can be by adding @IBDesignable/@IBInspectable.

Answer (score 0):

Not exact sure what you mean by "global" button. But if i have a button that call a `function` that is often reuse across multiple view controller, i usually create a `protocol` or `helper` object for the `function` depending on what is appropriate.

But if you "global" button refer to a button that is `floating` at the same place regardless of which `ViewController` the user is in, then i think you can can look at this. https://github.com/yoavlt/LiquidFloatingActionButton

This is a floating button like the one in Google Mail app.